# How to configure an Nginx > Varnish > uWSGI setup

Tags: django, nginx, varnish, uwsgi

I found this example http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example (see: Varnish and nginx, the best way (0.9.8.4)) which suggests putting Varnish between Nginx and uWsgi.

I'm trying to get this working for my Django site.

It's all running but when I use varnishlog, I don't see anything showing up when visiting my site. It seems that varnish is not doing much.

My configuration is:

Nginx: (replaced real domainname with 'domain')

```
upstream uwsgi_staging {
    server 127.0.0.1:3031;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    root /var/www/domain/staging/src/;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass uwsgi_staging;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

uWSGI:  (relevant part of .ini conf file used by emperor process)

```
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
protocol = http
module = website.wsgi:application
```

Varnish:

/etc/default/varnish

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,1G"
```

/etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
backend uwsgi {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "3031";
}


sub vcl_recv {    
    set req.backend = uwsgi;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the "restart daemon" part in the middle of [this post](http://www.howtoforge.com/putting-varnish-in-front-of-apache-on-ubuntu-debian) it might give you some answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varnish is only serving cached responses to requests without any cookies set. You need to make sure to unset unnecessary cookies to unleash the full power of varnish.

You may want to have a look in this [nice summary/example on dealing with cookie requests for varnish + django](http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2011/09/23/varnish-caching-for-unauthenticated-django-views.html)